# Displaying only the first item from the localStorage data array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to build a board that should display the first number from the list but I can't find `$.each` alternative.

Currently, I have a piece of code that displays all items from the `localStorage`. Does anyone have an idea of `jQuery` function that would take an array as argument and callback only the first item? Similar to this one - `$.each( array, callback )`.

```
const clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  const odontologas = clients.Odontologas;

  $.each(odontologas, function(i, item) {
    if (item.Būsena === "Eilėje") {
      $("#odontologasQueue").append(
        `<p class="boardNumber">${item.EilėsNr}</p>`
      );
    } else {
      $("#odontologasQueue").append(`<p class="boardNumber">000</p>`);
    }
  });
```

Comment: so why loop and not just look at the first index? `var item = odontologas[0]`....

Comment: Then it would always display the first item. I need to loop to find out which items are set to specific string and then display the first occurrence.

Comment: so than use find() on the array or exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add `return false` to `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

So either exit the loop when you find the match or use array.find

```
var first = odontologas.find(item => item.Būsena === "Eilėje")
// var first = odontologas.find(function(item) { return item.Būsena === "Eilėje" })
console.log(first)
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you want index of an entry? It's

```
odontologas.indexOf("Eilėje"); // equals -1 if element isn't found in the array
```